# QListWidget handling multiple signals from clicking and itemSelectionChanged

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a two list widgets which are essentially item selectors.  When I select an item in either list, I need it to trigger a method.  There is only one procedure in question here.  I need that procedure to happen when when the selection changes or when an item is clicked, but I don't want that thing to happen twice, which is the problem I'm having

Its a bit hard to describe but look at the code below.

Scenario 1: both lists only connect "itemSelectionChanged"
Click "Cheese"
Click "No"
Both are now selected and when you alternate clicking on them nothing happens because no selection is changing, but I need something_happened method to be called when I select an item from a different list.

Scenario 2: both lists only connect "clicked"
Upon clicking something happens, but as I click and drag to change the selection, no events are triggered, because "clicking" is not happening and itemSelectionChanged is not connected to anything.  I need the something_happened method to be called when the selection changes in this manner also.

Scenario 3: both lists connect "itemSelectionChanged" and also "clicked"
Clicking and dragging to change the selection makes something happen (good) but when I do a single "click" on a new item, both signals are sent and the event I want to happen, happens twice (bad).

Given the above scenarios I would like to achieve all of the following simultaneously:

- Handle **only one** event when I click a new item (which emits both itemSelectionChanged and itemClicked at the same time resulting in two events)
- Handle one event when I click an already selected item (which emits the itemClicked signal)
- Handle one event when I change the selection by clicking and dragging (which emits the itemSelectionChagned signal)

Here is the example code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
QtWidgets = QtGui
# from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
import time


def something_happened():
    print(time.time())

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(None)
vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)

list_widget1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(None)
list_widget1.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
list_widget1.addItems(("Cheese", "Whiz", "tastes", "great"))
list_widget1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(something_happened)
list_widget1.clicked.connect(something_happened)

list_widget2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(None)
list_widget2.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
list_widget2.addItems(("No", "it", "tastes", "bad"))
list_widget2.itemSelectionChanged.connect(something_happened)
# list_widget2.clicked.connect(something_happened)

vlay.addWidget(list_widget1)
vlay.addWidget(list_widget2)

widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example I am subclassing the QListWidget. It is not necessary, but I think that it will make the code cleaner if you encapsulate the decision of the selection-change within the widget itself. I made two types of widgets, each has its own behavior with regards to deciding if the selection changed. You could play around with mousePress/mouseRelease/selectionChanged combinations, hopefully this code will provide you with the tools you need. 
Run this program, and note the differences between the two widgets.

```
class SomeFrame(object):
    """A container to place all the widgets, and control
       present the output from the selections.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()

        # Creating content
        list_widget1 = MyQListWidgetA()
        list_widget1.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        list_widget1.addItems(("Cheese", "Whiz", "tastes", "great"))

        list_widget2 = MyQListWidgetB()
        list_widget2.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        list_widget2.addItems(("No", "it", "tastes", "bad"))

        # Creating Layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(list_widget1)
        layout.addWidget(list_widget2)

        self.frame.setLayout(layout)

        # Connections
        from functools import partial
        list_widget1.selection_changed.connect(partial(self.selectionChangedCB, 'list_1'))
        list_widget2.selection_changed.connect(partial(self.selectionChangedCB, 'list_2'))

        self.frame.show()

    def selectionChangedCB(self, list_name, selected_items):
        print(list_name + ' changed: ' + str(selected_items))


from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
class MyQListWidgetA(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    """This widget emits selection_changed whenever its
       itemSelectionChanged signal is emitted, AND there
       was an actual change in the selected items.
    """
    selection_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.__init__(self)

        self.selected_items = set()

        self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.something_happened)

    def something_happened(self):
        # Create a set of the newly selected items, so we can compare
        # to the old selected items set
        newly_selected_items = set([item.text() for item in self.selectedItems()])
        if newly_selected_items != self.selected_items:
            # Only emit selection_changed signal if a change was detected.
            self.selected_items = newly_selected_items
            self.selection_changed.emit(self.selected_items)


class MyQListWidgetB(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    """This widget emits selection_changed whenever it is pressed
       (mimic "clicked" signal) and again when the user is done
       selecting the items (mouse release) IFF the selection
       has changed.
    """
    selection_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.__init__(self)

        self.selected_items = set()

    def something_happened(self, initial_click=False):
        # Create a set of the newly selected items, so we can
        # compare to the old selected items set
        newly_selected_items = set([item.text() for item in self.selectedItems()])
        if newly_selected_items != self.selected_items:
            # Only emit selection_changed signal if a change was detected
            self.selected_items = newly_selected_items
            self.selection_changed.emit(self.selected_items)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        self.something_happened()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        self.something_happened()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)         
    theFrame = SomeFrame()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: I realized that I never accounted for "Handle one event when I click an already selected item (which emits the itemClicked signal)".
I take it as same-single-item-clicks, but it can also be solved for same-multiple-items clicks (use the mouseReleaseEvent, and compare old-new lists).
Just add MyQListWidgetC, and connect it to its two signals. The main difference between B and C is that in the mousePressEvent we check to see if a single item was pressed, and if it is the same item.

```
class MyQListWidgetC(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    """This widget emits selection_changed whenever it is pressed
       (mimic "clicked" signal) and again when the user is done
       selecting the items (mouse release) IFF the selection
       has changed. If a single item was clicked, AND it is the
       same item, the widget will emit same_item_clicked, which
       the owner can listen to and decide what to do.
    """
    selection_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    same_item_clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.__init__(self)

        self.selected_items = set()

    def something_happened(self, initial_click=False):
        # Create a set of the newly selected items, so we can
        # compare to the old selected items set
        newly_selected_items = set([item.text() for item in self.selectedItems()])
        if newly_selected_items != self.selected_items:
            # Only emit selection_changed signal if a change was detected
            self.selected_items = newly_selected_items
            self.selection_changed.emit(self.selected_items)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        newly_selected_items = set([item.text() for item in self.selectedItems()])
        if len(newly_selected_items) == 1 and newly_selected_items == self.selected_items:
            self.same_item_clicked.emit(self.selected_items)
        else:
            self.something_happened()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QListWidget.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        self.something_happened()
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks very much.  I like how you figured it out so that the object keeps track of itself.  I was thinking I would have to route all the signals from the lists through an outer object, but this is much better.  Thanks